# How to resolve my Fatal Error after uninstalling Views Chart Tools and Google Chart Tools

Tags: views, charts

I'm getting the below Fatal Error after I uninstalled the [Views Chart Tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_chart_tools) and the [Google Chart Tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_chart_tools) modules.

> Fatal error: views_plugin_display::destroy(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "views_chart_tools_plugin_display_dashboard" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded *before* unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition in /home/XXXX/XXXX/sites/all/modules/views/plugins/views_plugin_display.inc on line 272

I was working with them but they did not serve my purpose. After uninstalling them I started getting the above error.

I can't clear cache or even view the block admin page. Can anyone tell me what I can do to resolve this?

Comment: Have you erally uninstalled them? Or only disabled and then deleted their files? In other words, have you been on "uninstall" tab on modules page and performed their uninstall actions?

Comment: Yes, I went to the uninstall tab and ran the process to uninstall after disabling. I haven't removed the directories from the server, but I don't think that would cause this. THanks for your reply

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! This is a Q&A site, and answers are kept separated from the question. If you have an answer, write it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [Drush](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush) to clear the cache. If the cache still will not clear, do a [registry rebuild](https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild).

If after all that you still have the error, use Drush to enable, disable and uninstall the module again. Sometimes a full cycle can clean up gremlins like this.

Comment: I have completely removed the modules (Views Chart Tools + Google Chart Tools) front the server. I had to use the browser solution as I'm having issues getting Drush installed. Still to no avail. I still get the error after the rebuild returns DRUPAL_ROOT is /home/music2015/public_html.
Bootstrapping to DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_SESSION
Bootstrap caches have been cleared in DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_SESSION
Doing registry_rebuild() in DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_SESSION
Bootstrapping to DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL
Rebuilding registry via registry_rebuild_cc_all in DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL

Comment: Is there a way to completely flush via phpMyadmin?

Comment: Have you tried the re-install, re-uninstall cycle?

Comment: I had not, but I flushed all caches using phpMyadmin and it cleared the error. I will be installing Drush so I don't have to hunt down cpanel login creds in the future. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED - Used phpMyadmin and selected all cache tables then using the Empty option from the dropdown performed TRUNCATE on all cache fields. At this point cleared the cache that was throwing the error.